# Parentheses for negative integers

Tags: function-construction

Trying to standard create prime factors presentation, but can't seem to remove the parentheses:

```
f[n_] := If[PrimeQ[Abs[n]] == True, n, Sign[n] CenterDot @@ 
Table[If[FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m, 2]] < 2, FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m, 1]], 
Superscript @@ (FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m]])], {m, 1, Length@FactorInteger[Abs[n]]}]]

f[-96]
```

out:

$-(2^5\cdot 3)$

I'm sure I made a meal out of it, but as it it, it works. I tried to remove `-1` output with `Sign`, but getting parentheses. Is there a neat way to do this without?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pf[n_] := PrecedenceForm[CenterDot @@ Table[If[FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m, 2]] < 2, 
      FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m, 1]], Superscript @@ (FactorInteger[Abs[n]][[m]])], {m, 1, 
      Length@FactorInteger[Abs[n]]}], 10000];

f2[n_] := If[PrimeQ[Abs[n]] == True, n, Sign[n] pf[n]]

f2[-96]
```

[image]

See also:

[PrecedenceForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PrecedenceForm.html)

[tutorial / Operator Input Forms >> Operator Precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)

Comment: lovely! Thank you :)